# What happens for in-progress job when do restart java

Tags: java, spring, transactions, restart

When the java app in the middle of the service process restarts, waits for the process and after finishing that continued or does abort the process.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on which process we are talking about, in-flight http requests are killed, but this behaviour can be configured, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#web.graceful-shutdown.